# formatting abstract

Tags: formatting, abstract

How do i format the abstract title? Also, i thought this was built into latex, but in LEd it says it doesn't recognize it, so i add \usepackage{abstract}. Is this suppose to be like this.

Sorry new to latex, so still trying to get the hang of it.

Comment: it depends on your document class. Which one do you use?

Comment: @Stefan Kottwitz i am using report

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that the title of an abstract is usually just 'Abstract', hence the fact that instruction manuals often don't tell you how to change it. For the `report` class, you can do the following.

```
\documentclass{report}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{I want a different heading}
\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
This is the abstract.
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I dont want to change the title, but i want to format it differently. I would like to use arial font for it.

Comment: Just replace `I want a different heading` with whatever you want, including formatting commands.