# Error when using \begin{RÉSUMÉ}

Tags: errors, compiling, babel, french

I write a paper in French, I add a package `\usepackage[english,francais]{babel}` to use a French but when I write:

```
\begin{RÉSUMÉ} abstract in french \end{RÉSUMÉ}
```

I get the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment R\IeC {\'E}SUM\IeC {\'E} undefined.
```

and when I use:

```
\begin{R\'ESUM\'E} résumé en français \end{R\'ESUM\'E}
```

I get the same error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment R\'ESUM\'E undefined.
```

Comment: I think `[english,francais]` should be `[english,french]` instead.

Comment: a problem becomes the same. i think i can not make `RÉSUMÉ` as macro !

Comment: @MartinScharrer: While I'd use `french` as well, `francais` actually works, as Ulrike remarked at my answer. I was surprised as well.

Answer (score 17):

Changing your language in `babel` doesn't change the language of the commands, it only changes the hyphenation patterns, the *printed titles*  of e.g. the table of contents or the abstract, and, in the case of `french`, also the punctuation spacing (You can see below that there's space before the exclamation mark). Thus, you'll still need to use `abstract` as the environment's name.

While `francais` will work as an option for `babel`, I'd recommend using `french` instead (which does exactly the same), just so you won't get confused with the languages and keep all macros in English. Thanks to Ulrike for clarifying in the comments.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\title{Mon titre}
\author{C'est moi}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Bonjour.
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents

\section{Et voilà!}

\subsection{Bon alors}

C'est grandiose!

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In a modern installation the options `french`, `frenchb` and `francais` all load frenchb.ldf from Daniel Flipo. They are synonyms and it is simply a matter of taste which one you use. In (very) old systems `french` sometimes loaded `french.sty` from Bernard Gaulle.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Ah, I didn't know nor expect that, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help ...
But when i user `RÉSUMÉ` instead `Abstract` it doesn't work your solution :(


i want to write like this paper :
ftp://138.96.0.43/members/Didier.Parigot/PDFarticle/francesco/Donsez2006.pdf

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but if you want to change the abstract title (to _RESUMÈ_), you can use [Ian's solution here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17626/4012). You'll still have to use `abstract` as the environment's name. But I think Martin's already helped you on this one.

Answer (score 16):

You can't use non-English letters in macro and environment names. The special characters are often implemented as *active characters*, i.e. characters which are actually macros. As you can see in the error message `É` is expanded to `\IeC {\'E}`. Such non-expandable macro can't be used in environment names.

If you want to define a `RÉSUMÉ` environment yourself you should use `RESUME` instead. Note that the `babel` package does not translate the names of the macros and environments, but provides hyphenation patterns and language related macros and settings, like e.g. French quotes. The default environment for this is `abstract`. It might be possible to translate such names to French for people which have issues with English, but even then non-English letters are a no-go.

---

If you want the abstract title instead by `RÉSUMÉ` you need to use the `abstract` environment nevertheless, but switch the language to `french`.
The exact name can also be redefined manually:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}

%\renewcommand{\abstractname}{RÉSUMÉ}
\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
    French abstract ...
\end{abstract}

\selectlanguage{english}
\begin{abstract}
    English abstract ...
\end{abstract}

text text ...

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is no problem in Luatex: `\def\startRÉSUMÉ{}` works perfectly. However, it's probably not adviasable to use and rely on such a feature.

Comment: @Marco: Thanks, I thought that there might be a way for LuaTeX and maybe XeTeX, because they have native Unicode support. However, in general it can't be done with LaTeX.

Comment: then it's impossible to write `RÉSUMÉ` instead `abstract` ??

Like this paper :
ftp://138.96.0.43/members/Didier.Parigot/PDFarticle/francesco/Donsez2006.pdf

Comment: @user15992: You can of course get `RÉSUMÉ` as a headline, but there is no predefined `RÉSUMÉ` environment which does this. You need to use the `abstract` environment while the `french` language is active. See my updated answer for this.

Comment: @user15992: Clad that I could help. Please accept the answer which helped you most by clicking the tick symbol at the left top corner of the answer, just below the voting arrows. This concludes the question and assigns reputation to the answerer and also to you.

Answer (score 7):

Using babel won't translate the user interface! All the macro and environment names will stay the same. I don't know whether there are packages for doing this, but `babel` does not.

ConTeXt allows localising the user interface AFAIK.

Answer (score 4):

You should not translate environment names into French, any more than you would translate `\begin` and `\end`. Use `\begin{abstract}` and `\end{abstract}`. It is possible to change the heading from 'Abstract' to 'Resume' in your document, but how you achieve this depends on the document class that you are using.